# Export table data to excel from server side in nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel

I am using json2xls npm, here is my code below:

```
exports.exportContactsXlsx = function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    var xls = json2xls(data);
    fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
}
```

After clicking export button, successfully i got "data.xlsx" file, but when i hit Export button in UI, i want to get that data.xlsx is downloading in bottom left corner of chrome browser.

How to do that?

Answer (score -1):

To setup a download link, on your anchor tag use the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), and the `src` will be downloaded in the bottom corner

Comment: This is my jade tag:                                                                                 button.btn.btn-success.btn-sm(ng-click='exportDataXlsx()') Excel , how to set ? can you show some demo? i am a newbie